# Magento 2: Error during compile Incompatible argument type

Tags: magento, magento2

I have below error while running

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

```
Errors during compilation:
        Ves\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Author\Grid\Collection
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. Actual type: \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; File:
 app/code/Ves/Blog/Model/ResourceModel/Author/Grid/Collection.php
```

Ves/Blog/Model/ResourceModel/Author/Grid/Collection.php

```
namespace Ves\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Author\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Ves\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Author\Collection as AuthorCollection;

class Collection extends AuthorCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
protected $aggregations;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $storeManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
```

Edit 1:
\app\code\Ves\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Author\Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Ves\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Author;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Ves\Blog\Model\Author', 'Ves\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Author');
    }

}
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

check  the construct of the class : AuthorCollection  . it seems that it si not supporting ; \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface; but need an \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface object . so when you call the construct of the class AuthorCollection    you should use exactly the same type

share your class AuthorCollection so I could help you

Comment: Updated question with author collection.